# Could not load file or assembly 'SharpSvn-DB44-20-Win32.dll'

Tags: c#, svn, exception, 64-bit, sharpsvn

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3, StructureMap and SharpSvn.
Here's the code that I'm using:

```
public class SvnFileReader : ISvnFileReader
{
    private readonly string _svnAddress;

    public SvnFileReader(string svnAddress)
    {
        _svnAddress = svnAddress;
    }

    public void DownloadFiles(DirectoryInfo destination)
    {
        using (var svnClient = new SvnClient())
        {
            // checkout the code to the specified directory
            svnClient.CheckOut(new Uri(_svnAddress), destination.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code:

```
_svnFileReader.DownloadFiles(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"d:\test"));
```

I get the following error message:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///D:\Projects\SvnFileReaderDemo\bin\SharpSvn-DB44-20-Win32.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The module
>   was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You should exclude the SharpSvn DLLs from StructureMap automatic [assembly scanning](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm) for dependencies. This is an unmanaged library but because you have configured StructureMap to look for types in all dlls when it tries to load this one it breaks.</strike>

---

UPDATE:

If you are running this code on a x64 bit OS you may try downloading the specific [x64 SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/files/documents/180/4382/SSvn-1.6016.1637-x64.zip) which uses `SharpSvn-DB44-20-x64.dll`.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @šljaker, I don't know what code you have used to configure your DI container.

Comment: @šljaker, are you running this on x86 or x64 bit OS?

Comment: @šljaker, why are you using the Win32 library then? You need to download the x64 bit version of SharpSvn. There are two different downloads and NuGet packages.

Comment: @Darin, I tried to install both NuGet packages  but I always get the error message. For x84: 'Failed to add reference to SharpSvn-DB44-20-win32' and for x64: 'Failed to add reference to SharpSvn-DB44-20-x64'. That's way I tried to reference SharpSvn manually.

Comment: The SharpSVN-DB44-*.dll is only needed if you want to access file:/// repositories that use the BDB repository format. (SharpSvn was designed to handle the case where that file is missing: you just get a proper exception when you try to open such a repository).